# what's the difference between these 2 python codes? why different results?

Tags: python

I'm writing a dfs code like below:

```
def dfs(self, graph, node, path):
    if node==len(graph)-1:
        self.res.append(path)
    else:
        for i in graph[node]:
            path.append(i)
            self.dfs(graph, i, path)
            print(path.pop())
```

but got undesired result, while I changed the for loop code in dfs to:

```
self.dfs(graph, i, path+[i])
```

the result is what I want. But I could not figure out what's the difference of these 2 piece codes. Thanks

Comment: Is this a kind of trick question? Obviously the difference in code is what you have changed: `+[i]`. If you are talking about the difference in behaviour you will have to describe both behaviours.

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm-wise, I need more information about how you represent the graph to give more insight. But code-wise, the difference is caused by the fact that List in Python is **mutable**.
That means in your original code, when you `pop` the `path` list, the entry in the `res` will change accordingly. Check this by the following.

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = []

b.append(a)  # b = [[1,2,3]]
a.pop()      # now b = [[1,2]]
```

But when you change the argument to `path + [i]`, a new List is constructed, i.e. the `path` inside the next recursive call of `dfs` is decoupled from that in the previous one. Check this by the following.

```
a = [1,2]
b = []

b.append(a+[3])  # b = [[1,2,3]]
a.pop()          
# b is still [[1,2,3]], because the expression a + [3] will be evaluated to another List
```

Comment: thank you, I think your answer resolves my question.

Comment: thank you, I think your answer resolves my question.

Answer (score 0):

Te original version mutates path in each iteration of each recursion. The second version just makes a copy and adds an extra element. This copy is not bound to a name, it just get passed to the next level of recursion.